# Map function on object containing mutliple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, map-function

I have a props object, with a user comment array, and the userId array inside. Originally i only had the user comment array, and so i used the map function to style each comment individually. Now that i have two arrays inside my props object, is there a way to use the map function to style both the users comment and his id at the same time? Here is my attempt at it but it doesnt work:

```
import React from 'react'
import faker from 'faker'

const UserComment = (props)=> {
    var commentData = props.map(props=> {
        return(<StyleComment comment = {props.comment} key = {props.comment} author = {props.userIds} />)})

    return(null)//commentData)
}


const StyleComment = (props) => {
    // get time of comment

    return(
        <div className = 'comment'> 

                        <a href="/" className= "avatar"> 
                            <img alt ="avatar" src= {faker.image.avatar()}/>
                        </a>

                    <div className = 'name'>
                        <a href ="/" className = "author">
                            {props.author}
                        </a> 
                        <span className="metadata"> Today at 1.00pm </span>
                        <div className= 'content'>
                            <div className = 'text'>{props.comment}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the parent where the props are defined:

```
<UserComment comment = {this.state.usersComment} userIds = {this.props.userIds}/>
```

and here is a `console.log` of an example output for the props object:
[image: console.log]

Comment: Can you provide the datasource and, in turn, the expected output?

Comment: Post your data sample or tell us how they both array are related to each other?

Comment: ive added a console.log of the props object to the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass complete object to `UserComment` component,

```
<UserComment comment={this.state.usersComment} />
```

Then you can iterate like this,

```
const UserComment = (props)=> {
  console.log(props.comment);
    return props.comment.comment.map((comment,index) => {
            return <StyleComment key={comment} comment={comment} author={props.comment.userIds[index]}/>
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dv5a4v)

**Note:** Current array iteration and mapping is based on `index`, but you must have some relation between `comment` and `userIds` array to correctly map the data.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am slightly confused by one part though. If you pass in `props.comment.comment` into the map function how does the function know what `props.comment.userIds` is?

Comment: Ok. You are confused with the name. See you pass data to `UserComment` component using props and name of prop is `comment`. So in `UserComment` component you nned to use this prop using name so you write `props.comment`. Now `this.state.userComment` is the object which is being passed to `UserComment` component using `comment` props which itself contains `comment` and `userIds` array. so finally you need to use `props.comment.comment` and `props.comment.userIds`.

Comment: If you are still confuse, then pass the data with another name like `<UserComment usersComment={this.state.usersComment} />` and use like `props.usersComment.comment` and `props.usersComment.userIds`.